# system-resolved and bind9 Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: networking, server, dns

I'm running a bind9. All requests are resolved correctly. After some times, i'm facing the following:

- From clients all requests are correctly answered. "dig", "nslookup" etc works well for local and remote zones.
- On the bind9 server itself, requests for local zones are failing. "SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)" gives no answer, no error.
- If i restart systems-resolved.service all things works again.

I read things like manually overwriting /etc/resolv.conf. But that can't work, because the resolve service mastering this file and overwrite that again.